# How to group x axis labels in highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I have labels as dates rendering to x axis , I want to group them in months categories, for example if I am showing date for two months the days should be subcategorized into two months

Comment: Could you setup jsifiddle with your current case? Have you tried `tickPositioner` and/or `labels.formatter`?